# Arduino Ethernet Shield does not accept connections

Tags: tcp, arduino, ethernet

I have been playing around with an arduino ethernet shield, trying to get basic examples to work, to no avail. Here is my setup:

The Arduino Mega 2560 is connected to the computer via usb and the ethernet shield is stacked upon it. I have tried many variations of the examples that come with the arduino software, and none seemed to work properly.After lots of debugging with wireshark, I figured that:

- I can't use DHCP, because it just hangs at the `Ethernet.begin(mac)` call.
- When I try with a static ip, the `Ethernet.localIP()` function returns 0.0.0.0. However, I can ping my device from my computer using the ip I have set and the device seems to receive and send packets properly.The problem now is that for some reason it drops the tcp connections.E.g here is the code I run that comes the closest to working:

  ```
  #include <SPI.h>
  #include <Ethernet.h>


  byte mac[] = {  
    0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
  IPAddress ip(192,168,2,27);

  IPAddress server(192,168,2,52); 

  EthernetClient client;

  void setup() {
    // start the Ethernet connection:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
   // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
    Serial.begin(9600);
     while (!Serial) {
      ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
    }
    Serial.println("a");



    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("connecting...");


    if (client.connect(server, 23)) {
      Serial.println("connected");
    } 
    else {

      Serial.println("connection failed");
    }
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  }

  void loop()
  {
    // if there are incoming bytes available 
    // from the server, read them and print them:
    if (client.available()) {
      char c = client.read();
      Serial.print(c);
    }

    // as long as there are bytes in the serial queue,
    // read them and send them out the socket if it's open:
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
      char inChar = Serial.read();
      if (client.connected()) {
        client.print(inChar); 
      }
    }

    // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
    if (!client.connected()) {
      Serial.println();
      Serial.println("disconnecting.");
      client.stop();
      // do nothing:
      while(true);
    }
  }
  ```

Its basically the Ethernet/TelnetClient example.
I have set up a telnet server on my computer. Now this is the arduino/computer exchange:
[image: screenshot]

The arduino sends a RST packet, but my server goes on to send it the greeting and login prompt.
I have tried the same with an arduino uno, and have also tried disconnecting the usb and using another power supply.
So, what could be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried the basic DHCP Address Printer from the Arduino examples?

Comment: yes, and as I have explained in my question, it will hang in the Ethernet.begin(mac) call forever.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the connection to the shield, sometimes this shield if it is chinese version, It might have small short-circuit.

I tried disconnect the shield and connect with wire as like as [arduino website indicate for arduino uno](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet) (the connections with arduino mega aren't correct, so you need connect like arduino uno)

If it don't work , try change the arduino shield. I have a similar problem with the same shield , and normally the problem is the connection to the arduino. 
The example should work if the arduino is correctly connected

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, I found that Ethernet fails to initialize if an SD card is inserted and not initialized. So, either take the SD card out, or initialize the SD card:

```
Sd2Card card;
card.init(speed, pinSelect);
```

I have some Chinese (SunFounder) version of Ethernet Shield, so it might not be relevant to cards from other manufacturers.